# Delaying mouseenter function

Tags: jquery, function, hover, delay, mouseenter

I know there's a lot of questions about this one but I just can't get it to work with  my script.

I want to delay my hover-effect by a split second so that my buttons don't twitch around when you move the pointer across the screen.

I tried setTimeout like this:

```
$("#picnav ul li a").mouseenter(function () {

   setTimeout(function() {

      $(this).animate({ 
        'padding-top' : 191,
        'padding-right' : 0, 
        'padding-bottom' : 60, 
        'padding-left' : 0  
        }, '3000', "easeInOutQuint");

    }, 500);

    }).mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).animate({ 
        'padding-top' : 60,
        'padding-right' : 0,
        'padding-bottom' : 191,
        'padding-left' : 0,
      }, '3000', "easeInOutQuint");
});
```

but I keep getting the message "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'paddingTop' in undefined"

What am I missing here?

If you wanna check the site out you can do so [here](http://aronssons.macework.se)

Comment: Please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the relevant code. (This includes HTML, JavaScript and CSS).

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is... You need to use a closure

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` inside setTimeout will not refer to the actual element

you can make it work like this -

```
$("#picnav ul li a").mouseenter(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   setTimeout(function() {
      $this.animate({
```

Comment: This makes the delay active, which is good! But I don't wan't the function to execute unless you've had the pointer over the object for 500ms.

Comment: @user2906953 you'll have to clear your timeout inside mouseleave

Comment: How would I do this exactly?